# Find all appointments for specific date

Tags: django, datetime, django-queryset

My goal is to get all appointments (start_date and time) for current month and put them in a table under dates of the current month. For example show all dates of November (Monday, Tuesday, etc. and under the dates show the appointments that took place for that day.

Can you propose a way of doing that?

My first try is to get all dates of the month (November) and show them to template. Then get all appointments with start_date and time

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seat = models.ForeignKey(Seat, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    start_appointment = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    end_appointment = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
```

For example:

```
# Show dates of current month and show them in template
year = today.year
month= today.month
num_days = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
days = [datetime.date(year, month, day) for day in range(1, num_days+1)]
print(days)

days_list = []
for days in days:
   days_str = days.strftime('%A, %d')
   days_list.append(days_str)
   print(days_str)

#Query for the appointments, something like:
appointments = Appointment.objects.filter()....
```

Comment: Show your Appointment Model. So, that it helps to write query.

Comment: I forgot just did it. :) Thank you for comment...

Answer (score 0):

The query might look like this,

```py
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth, TruncYear, TruncDay

appointments = Appointment.objects.filter(
    start_appointment__gt="FILTERED DATETIME",
    end_appointment__lte="FILTERED DATETIME"
).annotate(
    year=TruncYear('start_appointment'),
    month=TruncMonth('start_appointment'),
    day=TruncDay('start_appointment'),
).values('year', 'month', 'day', ....)
```

This appointment will be grouped with year, month, day along with other values that you'll be provided. According to your need you can adjust them.
You can read more about on the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#datefield-truncation)

Comment: Thank you for the query but this is not what i want. I want to show all days of the month even if there is no booked appointment. Imagine something like a calendar but in a table. For example Monday(appointment) Tuesday(empty), etc. I'm currently showing all dates of the month but what is missing is to add appointments. I hope is clear..